# How can I add as many labels as number of the list elements to DataTemplete in CarouselView?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am developing an app using Xamarin Forms PCL.

I want to create a carousel view with a different number of buttons for each item.

This is my code.

```
public class Main {
    ObservableCollection<Data> Datas = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
    /* add some data */
    CarouselView carouselView = new CarouselView();
    carouselView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Datas");
    carouselView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>{
        var layout = new StackLayout();
        Label titleLabel = new Label();
        titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
        layout.Children.Add(titleLabel);
         
         //I want to do like this
         /*
         foreach(var body in Bodys) {
            var btn = new Button {
                Text = body
            };
            layout.Children.Add(btn);
        }
         */
        return layout;
    });

}

public class Data {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Bodys { get; set; } 
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does you want to add one button in the first items , then two in the second and so on ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT No. I want to add as many buttons as the size of "Bodys"  property.
LIke this
Bodys{"a"} → one button.
Bodys{"a","b","c"} → three buttons

Comment: It seems that you had implemented it .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It is just example. It doesn't work well :(

Comment: What means of  `doesn't work well` ? You could better provide more details .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT In DataTemplete lambda func, I couldn't get Bodys property of Data class so I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229685/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-roku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could use **[Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)**

```
<CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  />

                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Bodys}"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Margin="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                    <Button Text="{Binding .}"  />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

And in your ViewModels

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> Datas {get; set;}
```